# how to load and boot yocto image on the arm hardware?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded, yocto

I have generated a custom Linux image by yocto hob, and the output in the /tmp/deploy/images/qumearm folder like below:

```
xxx.rootfs.ext4          size:51MB

xxx.rootfs.tar.bz2       size:13.2MB

xxx.rootfs.manifest      (the compiled packages list file)
```

In this folder also have other files like:zimage,image-qumearm.bin.But I don't sure if zimage,image-qumearm.bin are the output file generated by this time.

Can anyone tell me ,how to load and boot the image on my arm board? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you got a .sdcard file, also?

Comment: Not found this file in the output folder.

Comment: Try to add `IMAGE_FSTYPES ?= "tar.bz2 ext3 sdcard"` to your local.conf. Let me know if the .sdcard is generated. If Yes I'll tell you how to flash your sd card.

Comment: For what machine you have built yocto images ? I think you are trying generate images for some hardware but selected machine type as `MACHINE ?= "qemuarm"`, e.g. for me for Beaglebone black I have enabled/uncommented `"MACHINE ?= "beaglebone""` in poky/build/conf/local.conf directory.

Answer (score 0):

On my hardware I'm using zImage flashed on SD card together with U-Boot SPL (preloader), U-Boot and rootfs. However it depends on your configuration. Typical boot scheme is: U-Boot SPL ->U-Boot ->LINUX_IMAGE. Where LINUX_IMAGE can be zImage or uImage.